# Resources on finding good Neural Network architectures for real applications

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have finished two neural network courses and done loads of reading on the subject. I am comfortable with Tensorflow and Keras and building advanced neural networks (multiple inputs, large data, special layers...). I also have a fairly deep understanding of the underlying mathematics.

My problem is that I know how to build neural networks but don't know the process by which an "expert" would create one for a specific application.

I can:

- Collect loads of data and clean it up.
- Train the neural network.
- Fine tune hyper parameters.
- Export it for actual applications.

What I am missing is how to come up with the layers in the neural network (how wide, what kind...). I know it is somewhat trial and error and looking at what has worked for others. But there must be a process that people can use to come up with architectures* that actually work very well. For example state of the art neural networks.

I am looking for a free resource that would help me understand this process of creating a very good architecture*.

*by architecture I mean the different layers that make up the network and their properties

Comment: I will keep doing courses and reading about neural networks and deep learning. If I find a resource that addresses my question I will answer my question.

Comment: It would also be useful to see someone go through the whole process of creating a neural network for a real application from start to finish. Not a NN that is exactly like another model but a brand new design that the creator came up with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my masters thesis about the topic:

> Thoma, Martin. "[Analysis and Optimization of Convolutional Neural Network Architectures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf)." arXiv preprint arXiv:1707.09725 (2017).

Long story short: There are a couple of techniques for analysis (chapter 2.5) and algorithms that learn topoligies (chapter 3), but in practice it is mostly trial and error / gut feeling.